# How can I wrap a span around a section of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

I'm trying to figure out how to target a section of characters from some generated HTML.

The output I have is:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y545JdKuHOs[/embed] This is some other copy.
</div>
```

The desired output is:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <span class="hide">
      [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y545JdKuHOs[/embed]
    </span> This is some other copy.
</div>
```

My goal is to wrap the `[embed]` tags in a `<span class="hide"></span>` that I can target via CSS. There are multiple instances of this HTML with different links inside the `[embed][/embed]` so I will most likely need to find a way to wrap the entire code into a span.

I was looking into `.wrap()`, but with no avail.you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `html()` method with a regular expression which pulls out the `[embed]*[/embed]` pattern and wraps it in a `<span>`. Try this:

```js
$('.entry-content').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/(\[embed\].+\[\/embed\])/gi, '<span class="hide">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.hide { background-color: yellow; } /* just for demo purposes */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
    [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y545JdKuHOs[/embed] This is some other copy.
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK45JuOsy5H[/embed] This is some other copy.
</div>
```